# How to give Groovy Script file path to GroovyScriptEngine?

Tags: java, groovy

I will want to load Groovy script file from the project resources folder..i am using this code

```
     GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine("/src/main/resources");
     Binding binding = new Binding();
     gse.run("UserSelectedComponents.groovy", binding);
```

But this code not working its telling file not exist.What i am doing wrong in path.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your path is wrong. You are using an absolute path, /src/main/resources, which will start from the root of your filesystem. This is probably not what you want.

So, either use the correct absolute path, or use a relative path, meaning removing the first slash. So it should look like

```
 GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine("src/main/resources");
 Binding binding = new Binding();
 gse.run("UserSelectedComponents.groovy", binding);
```

or

```
 GroovyScriptEngine gse = new GroovyScriptEngine("/user/home/subodh/project/groovy/src/main/resources");
 Binding binding = new Binding();
 gse.run("UserSelectedComponents.groovy", binding);
```

Comment: I dont want to use second this and when i am using your first path declaration i am getting Cannot open URL: file:/C:/Java/eclipse-juno/eclipse/src/main/resourcesUserSelectedComponents.groovy

Comment: Hi subodh, I've used a Unix path in my example. Try to make it a windows path instead, something like 'new GroovyScriptEngine("c:/Java/eclipse-juno/")' or GroovyScriptEngine("c:\\Java\\eclipse-juno\\"). I don't have access to a Windows machine to verify it.

Comment: Or are you saying you don't want to use the second one? Is the path correct?

Comment: yes i dont want to use second one i want to dynamic kind of path which work everywhere no matter its linux/Windows machine